# Area Number Code in EditText Box

Tags: android

Hi I have a registration form in my app and I have a phone number `EditText` box and I want to force the area code like (+233) so it is 
always visible as they are typing. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: You want it to be before all there text they type in?

Comment: Why don't you just put a fixed label next to the textbox so they can see that (+233) is already taken care of? Might provide a better UX

Comment: take a look for this library to add country code selector beside your edittext
https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

Comment: I really like the look of that @MGRagab thanks!